# rewrite requests for always on bot in linux Azure app service

Tags: node.js, azure, docker, azure-web-app-service

We are seeing some 404 logs coming from a bot in Azure always On. It trigged every 5min. Our health check is not in the root directory.

We are using Docker image for this, NodeJs 14.x. In documentation, they say to use web.config to redirect some urls but I'm not sure this will work.

```
<rule name="Redirect AlwaysOn requests from root to custom url" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^AlwaysOn$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/status" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
</rule>
```

and not sure where to put this file in the container. Here's docker file

```
FROM node:15.0.1-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN mkdir node_modules
RUN mkdir dist
COPY node_modules node_modules
COPY dist dist

COPY apps/api/.docker/sshd_config /etc/ssh/
COPY apps/api/.docker/init.sh /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/init.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/init.sh"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 404 logs coming from a bot in Azure always On.

- Issue can be  fixed by rewriting the  *Always on*  path.
- After a cold start of your application, ***AlwaysOn*** will send a request to the ***ROOT*** of your application “/”. Whatever file is delivered when a request is made to, / is the one which will be warmed up, it will fail because the root doesn’t exist.
- Make  ***AlwaysOn*** to warmup a specific page instead of the root,  implement ***URL Rewrite*** rule.

```cs
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no">
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite AlwaysOn" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^$"  />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="^AlwaysOn$"  />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/status" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

- ***web.config*** file needs to be added to the node app at the root
- If your app has a ***server.js*** or ***app.js*** file in your Node.js project, the ***web.config*** file should be in the same directory.
- If you are using ***Visual Studio Code*** , then   Put ***web.config*** file  in /public folder, It will then be copied over to /dist folder  during build.
- I have created the config file in public folder, After running  ***npm run build***  , web.config file is copied to dist folder.
  [image]
- To create web.config, Right click on the public folder
  Add new file, name it as web.config and add the above mentioned code snippet and save.
- Go to Azure portal, your Web App =>Advanced Tools=>KUDU - Debug Console =>CMD => site=>wwwroot , check if web.config file exists or not.

[image]

- If you are using Visual Studio, then select Azure Node.js Express template to craete the Web App, then web.config will be generated automatically.You can edit the settings directly.

[image]